# How to categories the same values of a column based on other column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table named **Appointments**, that looks like the below table -

| mrno | patencounterid | Doctor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1718 | 68 | Dr. A |
| 1718 | 69 | Dr. A |
| 1718 | 70 | Dr. A |
| 1718 | 71 | Dr. B |
| 1718 | 72 | Dr. B |
| 1718 | 73 | Dr. B |

I want to add a new column **Old & New** (Categorises the patients as Old and New).

**Necessary conditions for a new patient -**

1. mrno has to be the same.
2. Doctor has to be the same.
3. patencounterid has to be the smallest one.

**Necessary conditions for an old patient -**

1. mrno has to be the same.
2. Doctor has to be the same.
3. patencounterid should not be the smallest one.

The values in the **mrno** and **Doctor** columns are not distinct but the corresponding **patencounterid** values are distinct.

The result table should look like this -

| mrno | patencounterid | Doctor | Old & New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1718 | 68 | Dr. A | New |
| 1718 | 69 | Dr. A | Old |
| 1718 | 70 | Dr. A | Old |
| 1718 | 71 | Dr. B | New |
| 1718 | 72 | Dr. B | Old |
| 1718 | 73 | Dr. B | Old |

My Take on this (which is not correct) -

Add New Column

```
VAR minimum =
CALCULATE(
        MIN(Appointments[patencounterid]),
        ALLEXCEPT(Appointments,Appointments[mrno]),
        COUNTROWS(
             FILTER(Appointments, EARLIER(Appointments[mrno]) = Appointments[mrno])),
        COUNTROWS(
             FILTER(Appointments, EARLIER(Appointments[Doctor]) = Appointments[Doctor])),
        COUNTROWS(
             FILTER(Appointments, EARLIER(Appointments[patencounterid]) < Appointments[patencounterid])))
  
RETURN IF(
       Appointments[patencounterid] = minimum, "New", "Old")
```

The Above code returns the error  - A function filter has been used in a true/false statement that is used as a filter expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below code for new **COLUMN**-

```
Column = 

VAR maximum = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Appointments'[patencounterid]),
    ALLEXCEPT(Appointments,Appointments[mrno])
)

RETURN IF (Appointments[patencounterid] = maximum, "New","Old")
```

Here is the output-

[image]

---

For your new requirement, try this below code-

```
Column = 

VAR minimum = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN('Appointments'[patencounterid]),
    ALLEXCEPT(Appointments,Appointments[mrno],Appointments[Doctor])
)

RETURN IF (Appointments[patencounterid] = minimum, "New","Old")
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Nice to see it worked and helped.

Comment: Dear mkRabbani, your solution worked but the question had more to it. I have edited the question and provided my tried solution as well which is not correct. I have added a few more lines to your code but it's showing error.

Comment: Hi @Atif, please check my updated answer. It's always great if you can post a new question rather than change an accepted question/answer.

Comment: Noted, Next time this won't happen.